# how to load data from DB after redirecting in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making an app in angular and node.js. I have a listing page where I list multiple products. When a user clicks on any product, it will go to `view_product` page where details of product is being shown. When Admin wants to delete a product from `view_product` page, then it will delete the product but when it redirects to listing page, then it does not show listing untill Admin refresh and compile whole app again. My code looks like following to redirect.

```
 this.router.navigate(['/listing']);
```

I'm fetching product in `ngOnInit()`. I think I need to call that method somehow when it navigates. But if I navigate from `view_product` page to `listing` using a link, then it shows products just fine. Here is how my navigation link looks like:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/listing']">Listing</a></li>
```

What am I missing? I need to redirect programatically from `view` to `listing`. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329985/angular-4-ngoninit-not-called-after-router-navigate see if this post helps.

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint to check if the control breaks inside `ngOnInit`