# ngOnInit don't execute when using router.navigate

Tags: angular, refresh, router, ngoninit

I've this simple app where `'/personas'` shows a list of `Persona` objects. There is also a button to add another person, which send to you to `/personas/agregar`. There you can create a new object and send it to firebase. Once you do it, the server should take you to `/personas` again and you should see all objects, however it doesn't shows the new one unless you refresh.

This is the code (when you submit the form it trigger guardarPersona() method):

personas.component.ts:

```
export class PersonasComponent implements OnInit {

  personas: Persona[] = [];

  constructor(private personasService: PersonasService, private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Persona[]) => {
        this.personas = personas;
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas);
      }
    );

  }
  
  personaAgregada(persona: Persona){
    this.personas.push(persona);
  }

  agregar(){
    this.router.navigate(['personas/agregar'])
  }

}
```

formulario.component.ts:

```
guardarPersona(){
    if(this.id){
      this.personasService.modificarPersona(this.id, this.nombreInput, this.apellidoInput);
    }else{
      this.personasService.agregarPersona(new Persona(this.nombreInput, this.apellidoInput));
    }
    this.router.navigate(['personas']);
  }
```

persona.service.ts:

```
setPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
    this.personas = personas;
  }

  obtenerPersonas(){
    return this.dataService.cargarPersonas();
  }

agregarPersona(persona: Persona) {
    if(this.personas == null){
      this.personas = [];
    }
    this.personas.push(persona); 
    this.dataService.guardarPersonas(this.personas);
  }
```

data.services.ts:

```
cargarPersonas(){
        return this.httpClient.get<Persona[]>('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json');
    }
    

    guardarPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
        this.httpClient.put(this.url + '.json', personas).subscribe(
            response => {console.log(`Datos enviados correctamente: ${response}`)},
            error => {console.log(`Error al enviar los datos: ${error}`)}
        );
    }
```

I've tried to solve it following [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254), using NgZone but it din't worked:

```
this.ngZone.run(() =>i {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('personas');
    });
```

I also tried with reloading the page after navigate but it neither send the information to firebase:

```
this.router.navigate(['personas']).then(() => {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Then I tried with modifying ngOnInit based in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329985/angular-4-ngoninit-not-called-after-router-navigate):

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      (event: Event) => {
             if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                  this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
                    (personas: Persona[]) => {
                      this.personas = personas;
                      this.personasService.setPersonas(personas);
                    }
                  );
             }
      });
  }
```

But I get `no overload matches this call` error

Comment: This is because `ngOnInit` fires once the component is created and if you navigate back to the list, the component is already created, so `ngOnInit` won't fire once again. Subscribing to the routing event is a good idea or you move the api call to a service and call it if necessary.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I delete the navigate sentence, when adding a person and press navigator's back button it shows the updated list, and when using navigate I asume that it's creating the component again... Even I tried copying the ngOnInit script and implement ngOnChange but doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Doing some test I realized that I was wrong, `ngOnInit()` was executing after `navigate()`, however it wasn't showing the updated list because `guardarPersonas()` takes too long and `ngOnInit()` gets the list before it's updated.

I "solve" this by setting a timeout on `navigate()`, but I wonder if it's a better way to do this, for example waiting for `httpClient.put` to finish.

Comment: **No**, You can not trust setting a time. You need call to navigate "inside subscribe" or, if you're using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush use [markForCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes)

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks! That's what I needed! I injected ```Router``` to ```DataService``` and call ```navigate()``` inside subscribe and it's working perfect now.